# Can't install audio_common (unment dependencies)

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, sound-play, dependencies, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm not being able to install the audio_common stack.

I'll list everything I've tried:

---

1. `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-audio-common`

output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-audio-common : Depends: ros-hydro-audio-capture but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-audio-common-msgs but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-audio-play but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ros-hydro-sound-play but it is not going to be installed
 ros-hydro-rosbag : Depends: ros-hydro-rosbag-storage but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

2. `sudo apt-get -f install ros-hydro-audio-common`

same output as shown above

---

3. I've tried installing only one of the packages by using `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sound-play`

output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-rosbag : Depends: ros-hydro-rosbag-storage but it is not going to be installed
 ros-hydro-sound-play : Depends: festival but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: festvox-kallpc16k but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-hydro-audio-common-msgs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

I'm having the same problem (unment dependencies) when I've tried installing others packages. Does anyone know what is causing this?

EDIT:

4. `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 ros-hydro-rosbag : Depends: ros-hydro-rosbag-storage but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187386/can%27t-install-audio_common-(unment-dependencies)/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing with aptitude, it gives you options to resolve conflicts.

you need to install aptitude first :

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

then

```
sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-audio-common
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-22**:
Thanks for the reply! I've edited the question with the output of the command to install aptitude. I've tried installing the libcwidget3 package, but it also outputs an 'unmet dependencies' error.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-22**:
do sudo apt-get autoremove and try

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-22**:
Thanks, it worked!